# Batch file launched in an exe doesn't work

Tags: c++, sql-server, batch-file

Ok so I have an executable which launches my batch file and the batch file then should create an ODBC data source to my SQL server. If I run the batch file by itself it runs perfectly and creates the data source, but when I run it through my exe it runs, returns no errors but doesn't create the data source.

my entire exe code is

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

cout << system("find2.bat");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

and my batch command is

```
ODBCCONF.exe CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Server" "DSN=test_DSN | Description=test Data Source |      SERVER=(local) | Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

I also tried to output any errors from the batch file but it just created a blank text file so I guess no errors.
So does anybody have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the batch file is running? Since you're not building an absolute path, I would guess it's not being found.

Comment: no the batch file is being found because the contents of it is displayed in the console. At first I thought this meant it was simply outputting the contents of the file but I added
     > test.txt 2>&1
to the end of the line and it created a text file for me with nothing in it. Which means the contents are being run, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you add echo commands to the batch file, do those appear? If yes, that would make the call to `ODBCCONF.exe` the culprit. It it found? Does it require admin privileges that you have at the command line but not when calling the batch file from the exe? Just guessing :-)

Comment: Yes the echo commands work as normal and I have my exe set to require admin rights and also if I run my batch file without admin rights it usually gives a pop up message about not having permission to create a data source. Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately I tried most of them already with no luck :( and to make it worse I tried to remove the privileges from the exe and as expected, it gives me the cant write error on running the batch file ... grrrr....

Comment: When you call the batch file from the exe, is the current directory the same as when you call it from the command prompt?

Comment: Yes :( here is the entire output of the command promt just after I click my exe file


C:\Users\kb\Desktop>ODBCCONF.exe CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Server" "DSN=GRP_DSN | Descri
ption=GRP Data Source | SERVER=(local) | Trusted_Connection=Yes"

C:\Users\kb\Desktop>ECHO TEST
TEST
0

Comment: Is this Windows? If ODBCCONF is the ODBC configuration tool which I know (I always just used the GUI), there are separate 32bit and 64 bit versions of it, residing in different locations. Maybe that (and Windows path virtualization) has something to do with it.

Comment: Yes it is Windows and hmmmm... maybe! I hadnt though of that, but running the batch file works perfectly, its only when I launch it from the executable that nothing happens, the only thing I can think of is the SERVER=(local) could be it but I've no idea why it wouldn't work. But might as well check it! Such a strange thing!

Comment: I have odbcconf.exe in c:\windows\system32 and in c:\windows\syswow64.

Comment: I tried giving the direct server name and same result..Nothing! and Yes I have odbcconf.exe in the exact same directories.

Comment: Could you verify the same odbcconf.exe is being called in both cases? I have a feeling the architecture your application is compiled for (32 or 64 bit) determines the odbcconf.exe that is called, so it may differ from what happens from the command line. Just a gut feelng, though.

Comment: Oh yes your right! the 64 bit version doesn't create the data source, where as the 32 bit does perfectly, so it must just be calling the incorrect one, ok now to test but I have a good feeling this should be the reason for it! Thank you so much! test time!

Comment: and actually it doesnt make a difference >:(

Comment: Not sure what you tried, but this is what I would do: Copy one odbcconf.exe to a path like c:\test and call it using that *absolute* path from the batch file. Then you will know for sure which one is being called (otherwise path virtualization may lead you astray). Then copy the other odbcconf.exe to the same path. With this setup, is there still a difference between calling the batch file directly from the command prompt as opposed to from the exe?

Comment: YES!!!! you where spot on there! I tried using the absolute paths to each windows directorys and that still changed nothing when run from the exe but I copied the 32 bit one to another directory and it worked perfectly! I can't thank you enough! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the call according to this:

```
system("cmd /c C:\\path\\to\\find2.bat");
```

Comment: NO this didn't help either, the batch file is being found and run as far as I can tell so maybe its a problem with the SQL call, but theres no problem with that when running the file by itself.